# MSK, IAM, and Kafka Java Api

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, aws-msk

So for some reason I can't get my connections just right with MSK via the Kafka Java API. I can get producers/consumers to work with MSK using [conduktor](https://www.conduktor.io) and Kafka CLI tools. However when I try to hook up my Scala code I can't get it to work. So I am using the config as follows to connect via `conduktor` and Kafka CLI tools.

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
sasl.jaas.config = software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandle
```

and for my Scala application I am setting up producers/consumers using a similar pattern

```
def props: Properties = {
   val p = new Properties()
   ....
   p.setProperty("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
   p.setProperty("sasl.mechanism", "AWS_MSK_IAM")
   p.setProperty("sasl.jaas.config", "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;")
   p.setProperty("sasl.client.callback.handler.class", "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler")
   p
}

val PRODUCER = new KafkaConsumer[AnyRef, AnyRef](props)
```

So the code works when I omit the security config lines and run against a local instance of Kafka but when I try to hit the MSK it seems like it isn't constructing a consumer and I get the following error.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can only check the position for partitions assigned to this consumer.`

However, the locally running instance works. So this makes me think I'm not setting up something correctly in the config to connect to the MSK.

I am trying to follow the following [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/securing-apache-kafka-is-easy-and-familiar-with-iam-access-control-for-amazon-msk/) and I am using Scala 2.11 and Kafka versions 2.41. I also added the `aws-msk-iam-auth` to my build.sbt (`1.1.0`). Any thoughts or solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to not be a problem with my AWS connection as I implemented some logging as explained [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-kafka-streams/content/kafka-logging.html). My problem lies in the difference between my local running version of Kafka and MSK. I am still trying to understand the differences.